# Linq - How to use a where clause that has a string but need to select on -1

Tags: c#, linq

I need to use a where clause to exclude rows that have a minus one.

The c.Bill_Ship_To_Code is a string.  My variable is a -1.

How can I create my where clause to select on an int from a string.

```
  var customerModel = db.CUSTOMERS
      .Where(c => c.Customer_ID == currentUser.PinCode && c.Bill_Ship_To_Code != -1);
```

Comment: Would `c.Bill_Ship_To_Code != "-1"` work?

Comment: Thanks very much.  Over thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Use `"-1"` or - if it's a variable - `num.ToString()`. Both must be the same type:

```
.Where(c => c.Customer_ID == currentUser.PinCode && c.Bill_Ship_To_Code != "-1");
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Over thinking.